# Follow a height of a control with an attached div

Tags: css, html, height

I have a fieldset (left) div (right) pair. The content of fieldset is fix, but it has hide()/show() elements, like a [Next] button. As these controls toggles, it changes the height of the fieldset control. I'd like to follow this height with the div on the right side. How? This is not a resize event...

```
-<fieldset>-----------------------<div>-----
|                                |         |
|                                |         |
|                                |         |
|                                |         |
|                                |         |
|                                |---------|
|             [Next]             |         
----------------------------------
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="attach">
    <p>something</p>
</div>
<fieldset class="left">
    <p>lotsa content</p>
    <p class="message">
        <button id="n" type="button">Next &gt;</button>
        <span></span>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    width: 720px;
}
fieldset.left {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
div.attach {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: thin solid LightGray;
    right: 1px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 242px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the contents of the right area will not overflow the container you can use absolute positioning like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vasmB/2/

This is the important bit:

```
left: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0;
```

By setting left to 100% you will always have the box on the right of the original container, regardless of it’s width. Top / bottom set to 0 will keep the height flexible.

Comment: Thx Chris, your example with the left % solved my problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting them both inside another div and giving the existant one a:

```
div.attach {
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. When I used a container div, its height was zero, the contents overlapped. Maybe I mixed something...

Comment: You should actually give the container's div a height in order for that to work. I haven't test it but that is how I would try to approach it myself first.